# Ternary operator is not returning undefined

Tags: javascript, algorithm, undefined, conditional-operator

I'm working on an FCC intermediate algorithm "Arguments Optional". Here's the instructions on what needs to happen:

> Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Arguments Optional

1. Create a function that sums two arguments together. If only one argument is provided, then return a function that expects one argument and returns the sum.
2. For example, addTogether(2, 3) should return 5, and addTogether(2) should return a function.
3. Calling this returned function with a single argument will then return the sum:
   var sumTwoAnd = addTogether(2);
   sumTwoAnd(3) returns 5.
4. If either argument isn't a valid number, return undefined.

I wrote the code to do everything explained above, but one requirement is that the arguments must all be numbers, otherwise return `undefined` (#4 above). You'll see I wrote a ternary operator (line 5 of my code) `numbersOnly` variable that I thought would handle this, but it's just returning [Function] in the console.

```
function addTogether() {
    // Convert args to an array
    let args = [...arguments];
    // Only accept numbers or return undefined and stop the program
    const numbersOnly = value => typeof(value) === 'number'? value : undefined;
    // test args for numbersOnly and return only the first two arguments regardless of the length of args
    let numbers = args.filter(numbersOnly).slice(0, 2);

    // // It has to add two numbers passed as parameters and return the sum.
    if (numbers.length > 1) {
        return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
    }
    // If it has only one argument then it has to return a function that uses that number and expects another one, to then add it.
    else if (numbers.length === 1) {
        let firstParam = numbers[0];
        return function(secondParam) {
            if (typeof secondParam !== 'number' || typeof firstParam !== 'number') {
                return undefined;
            }
            return secondParam + firstParam;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm passing all of tests, with the exception of #4, which should return undefined. I don't quite understand why 5 is passing and returning undefined but 4 is failing. What am I missing here? Thanks!

```
1. addTogether(2, 3) should return 5.
2. addTogether(2)(3) should return 5.
3. addTogether("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ") should return undefined.
4. addTogether(2, "3") should return undefined.
5. addTogether(2)([3]) should return undefined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because you have to check input args and output args from filter.
Try to add this snippet:

```
let numbers = args.filter(numbersOnly).slice(0, 2);
if (args.length > numbers.length) {
  return undefined;
}
```

```js
function addTogether() {
    // Convert args to an array
    let args = [...arguments];
    // Only accept numbers or return undefined and stop the program
    const numbersOnly = value => typeof(value) === 'number'? value : undefined;
    // test args for numbersOnly and return only the first two arguments regardless of the length of args
    let numbers = args.filter(numbersOnly).slice(0, 2);
    if (args.length > numbers.length) {
      return undefined;
    }

    // // It has to add two numbers passed as parameters and return the sum.
    if (numbers.length > 1) {
        return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
    }
    // If it has only one argument then it has to return a function that uses that number and expects another one, to then add it.
    else if (numbers.length === 1) {
        let firstParam = numbers[0];
        return function(secondParam) {
            if (typeof secondParam !== 'number' || typeof firstParam !== 'number') {
                return undefined;
            }
            return secondParam + firstParam;
        }
    }
  }
  console.log('4. addTogether', addTogether(4, "4"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you filter the arguments, only `'3'` gets filtered out, so the length of the remaining array is 1.

```js
const args = [2, '3'];
const numbers = args.filter((n) => typeof n === 'number');
console.log('numbers:', numbers);
console.log('numbers.length === 1:', numbers.length === 1);
```